# JSON API and translations with Ember Data

Tags: json, api, ember.js, ember-data

What's the best JSON API architecture for easy usage with Ember Data, mobile SDKs, ... and why knowing that each page can have a different number of translations?

The write interface, is currently made using *option 2) inline*.

**Option 1) As Hash**

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: {
        en: "Title",
        fr: "Titre"
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Option 2) Inline**

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title_en: "Title",
      title_fr: "Titre"
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest giving http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html a look if you're interested in pursuing option 1.

Comment: Thanks @locks , if I remember well their's some issues with dirty tracking when using such method. Do you have experience with such approach?

Comment: I don't, only with sideloading HAL+JSON embedded records, which are a slightly different topic.

Answer (score 0):

To use Ember Data and to best utilize its side loading capabilities you need to keep your data structure relational, something like below

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title_ids: [1,3]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title_ids: [2,3]
    }
  ],
  titles: [
      {
        id: 1,
        en: "Title",
        fr: "Titre"
        ...
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        en: "Title",
        fr: "Titre"
        ...
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        en: "Title",
        fr: "Titre"
        ...
      },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @lame_coder
I don't think flatting the translations as new object would make sense here. Each translation's set is uniq to a page (they won't be cases where you end up loading multiple time the same translations in multiple page) but also their's no internal ID for this translations, giving IDs would imply a complete new model with all it's CRUD actions which feels a bit overcomplicated I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to this [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/), then use [this adapter](https://github.com/daliwali/ember-json-api).

If you are referring to JSON APIs in general, then I would say that either of the options that you have presented is fine, but just think about how you are going to present it in your handlebars templates. IMHO, I would take a slight twist on option #1 (hash).

Instead of this:

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: {
        en: "Title",
        fr: "Titre"
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would do this instead:

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      translations: {
        en: {
            title: "Title"
        },
        fr: {
            title: "Titre"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then for the controller you could do this:

```
App.PagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    currentLanguage: 'fr',

    translatedPages: function() {
        var translationKey = 'translations.'+this.get('currentLanguage');
        return this.get('model').map(function(page) {
            return {
                id: page.get('id'),
                content: page.get(translationKey);
            };
        });
    }.property('currentLanguage'),
});
```

And in the handlebars template, you could do this:

```
{{#each page in translatedPages}}
    {{#link-to page.id}}
        <p>{{page.content.title]}}</p>
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

When designing the structure of the returned JSON,
my primary consideration was how straightforward it would be to create
a computed property (in this case `translatedPages`),
to be displayed in a standard Handlebars template,
without the need to define any custom Handlebars helpers,
or Ember Components. 
If you have some more complex requirements,
I would suggest those. 
For this, however, a simple solution is possible.

Comment: I like your solution, but how do use ember-data for a model like this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to display multiple languages simultaneously on the same page?

If you are just displaying the data in one language at a time, then passing an `Accept-Language` header to your backend and getting a response in only that language is probably the more appropriate solution since.

In my particular case I just used `ajaxSetup` with something like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({headers: {'Accept-Language': 'en_US'}});
```

Returning something like

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Title"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I also needed to know which languages were available I would supply a language parameter. Something like:

```
{
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      lang: ['en_US', 'fr_FR']
      title: "Title"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's a good way for public display, I agree. However I also need this Ember App to manage the translations, so all CRUD actions are required.

Comment: @SébastienGrosjean-ZenCocoon You can still do CRUD, just have `Accept-Language` be the language you're working in.

Comment: @SébastienGrosjean-ZenCocoon Or add another header or parameter to be explicit about the data you're sending back.

Comment: we allow to update multiple translations at onces so having title_fr, title_en makes it convenient.

Answer (score 0):

[ember-data-model-fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data-model-fragments) seem to fit nicely into your use case.

But I would attempt a completely different solution. I would split the model into two parts, e. g. `post` and `post-translation`. A single post would look like this then:

```
{

  id: '1'
  type: 'post',
  relationships: {
    translations: [
      {id: '1', type: 'post-translation'},
      {id: '2', type: 'post-translation'}
    ]
  }
}

{
  id: '1'
  type: 'post-translation',
  relationships: {
    post: {id: '1', type: 'post'}
  },
  attributes: {
    lang: 'en',
    title: 'Hello world!',
    body: "Wonderful weather we have today, don't we?"
  }
}

{
  id: '2'
  type: 'post-translation',
  relationships: {
    post: {id: '1', type: 'post'}
  },
  attributes: {
    lang: 'ru',
    title: 'Здравствуй, мир!',
    body: 'Чудесная погодка сегодня, не так ли?'
  }
}
```

This approach will also let you collect language-specific comments to posts.